# Excel - Non-Volatile alternative to INDIRECT within INDEX/MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula, index-match, non-volatile

I'm looking for a Non-Volatile alternative for INDIRECT within my INDEX/MATCH Formula.
After spending a lot of time building my Excel Payroll Application I learned about volatile Functions, INDIRECT in particular. I have 1,342 of these bad boys on four of my sheets for the sole purpose of returning values using INDEX/MATCH and now Calulating takes forever.

Below is the INDEX/MATCH Formula with two criteria, Pay Date & Employee Name, I'm using on my 'Employee Pay Slips' Worksheet.

=INDEX(INDIRECT(PostSht &"!$E$9:$E$1009"),MATCH(1,((INDIRECT(PostSht &"!$B$9:$B$1009")=E7) * (INDIRECT(PostSht &"!$C$9:$C$1009")=E10)),0),0)

- PostSht is a Dynamic Named Range (a Cell actually) in which the
  Month/Worksheet Name, January to December, gets posted via VBA.
- E9:E1009 is the Range where the requested Value is located.
- B9:B1009 is the Range where the Date is located (MATCH Range1).
- E7 is the Cell with a Pay Date Value (MATCH Criteria1).
- C9:C1009 is the Range where the Employees' Name is located  (MATCH Range2).
- E10 is the Cell with an Employee Name Value (MATCH Criteria2).
- The MATCH function of the Formula will remain the same for every
  instance of this formula as those criteria will always be Pay Date
  and Employee Name
- The INDEX [column_num] option remains at 0 because I already
  specified the Column with the INDEX array.
- The two variables are the Month (PostSht=Month/Worksheet Name) and
  the Column (E in this case). The Rows remain the same (9-1009).

Not sure if this helps but I have a list of of all months as a named Range called Sheets on a VeryHiddenSheet Helper Sheet. I'm open to expanding that list to add a column with additional values (Not sure what values though). I'm also open to learning more about optimizing the PostSht Named Range to include a CHOOSE Formula as well.

I looked at different alternatives such as CHOOSE and INDEX but I can't seem to get it right for my formula above and I've looked at many examples but I didn't see any for my application of a Dynamic Worksheet Name within INDEX/MATCH.

I look forward to your replies and open to all non-volatile suggestions. Thanks in advance. Derick....

Comment: Since the sheet name is what is dynamic there is no alternative to using INDIRECT except vba.

Comment: That answer is what I feared and hoping not to learn. Thanks. I guess my query has changed in to finding a VBA solution.

Comment: Use a Worksheet_Change that focusses on the cells that change the target sheet.  When those change, rewrite the formula so they point to the correct sheet.  It may be slow on changing sheets but will not slow down the rest of excel.

Comment: An alternative is to consolidate the data onto a single sheet.  If you don't want to simply move the data, then consider a union query to dynamically consolidate it

Comment: @ScottCraner, There's 1100 fields with INDEX/MATCH Queries with 3,300 INDIRECT Functions for automatic population when the date and name is entered. Your idea of Worksheet_Change is great. I have a Macro attached to a button to insert all Employees Names and Pay Date into thier respective cells. I'll remove all formulas from the cells and use VBA to enter the values needed. I'll modify that Macro to fill in those 11 fields as well. Using a copy to test this out

Comment: Good idea @chrisneilsen, Get the values from one sheet instead of using a dynamic sheet name, January to December, Just use a static sheet. I do have a MasterData Sheet already that consolidates all Months with a Pivot Table after the Pay Information is posted to the respective rows on that months' sheet. I think this would be less work than VBA and I wont need to use INDERICT at all.

Comment: Thank you Scott and Chris. I now have two additional options thanks to you. I'll give both serious considerations as I have all the ground work done already to implement either option.